# EAGLE CAD: Push aside traces by DRC clearance

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout, cad

Does anyone know of a script or tool which makes it easier to 'push aside' traces when routing by the specified DRC spacing? For example, if I have 2 traces which should be parallel and are 6 mils wide and 6 mils apart it is fine to route on a 12 mil grid if I am strictly routing horizontally or vertically. However, if I try to route on the same grid diagonally, they will be too close together, just due to geometry.

Some PCB layout programs have a push aside or 'shove' command which does exactly this. Is there a native command or script which performs this function in EAGLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to do this, and no ULPs that I'm aware of. However, you can use the "follow-me" router to easily redraw your traces -- the program will not let you violate DRC while doing this. You need to have the Autorouter package to do this.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the 'follow-me' router.